# how to use SNMP on Linksys PAP2T?

Tags: voip, snmp, linksys

I've posted it to serverfault earlier, but had no response... Help me, please!

I have to monitor a network. In this network there are several voip devices, some of them are Linksys PAP2T. I'd like to get the name of this device over the network. For all other SNMP works fine, but how can I use SNMP on PAP2T or is there any replace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the product data sheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/csbpvga/pap2t/administration/guide/pap2t_user.pdf), as far as I understand 'Linksys PAP2T' does not support SNMP at all.

Comment: that's bat, but thanks! don't you know any replace?

Comment: Sorry no, perhaps using cisco application to relay state on SNMP or HTTP client application. If it's confirmed validate the answer.

Comment: I'm going to check this today, and surely i'll validate the answer

Comment: you are right. i can obtain the state from linksys, but not it's name

Comment: Yes, this limitation is an artificial discrimination between enterprise and consumer products. You should be able to scrape its web interface for the relevant data using wget or curl.

Comment: What do you mean "name"? Whether it's a PAP2 or not? Or its hostname? Or the SIP username it registers with? If the SIP proxy it registers at is under your management, you might be able to get all the information from there.